# How can I split a textstring using razor (in Umbraco)?

Tags: asp.net, razor, split, umbraco

I'm relatively (more like completely) new to the world of razor, and have inevitably hit my first hurdle. I'm a web developer who is also new to the CMS Umbraco, and therefore I've been working with razor for scripting.

My problem is rather a simple one I believe; how can I split a textstring to display 4 different words/values, with commas in between?

Ideally, I would like to turn something like:

"WhyWontThisWork" into "Why, Wont, This, Work" and to possibly complicate things: "'Why', Wont, This, Work" (with the 's around the first word)

I"ve been trying with this method from another thread, but to no avail:

```
@foreach (string s in "1,2,3".Split(',')) {
  @: s is equal to @s<br/>
}
```

By trying to implement this syntax into my own script, it looks like the following, and therefore it doesn't work:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@{
    foreach (var x in Model.uctextstring.Split(',')) {
        @x.InnerText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an issue specifically to tackle with Razor. I think the best way of doing this would be to have a dedicated method. Simple splits won't do what you want because you don't know the logical point at which to split, and I can't think of an easy Regex solution for it either. So here is a very basic example that moves through the string character by character to identify basic word boundaries:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitString(string value)
{
  char last = char.MinValue;
  bool inWord = false;
  string word = string.Empty;

  foreach (char c in s)
  {
      if (char.IsLetter(c))
      {
          // Covers situations with apostrophised characters, e.g. 's
          if (last == '\'' && char.IsLetter(c) && inWord)
          {
              word += last;
              word += c;
              yield return word;

              word = string.Empty;
              inWord = false;
          }
          else if (char.IsUpper(c) && !inWord)
          {
              // Start of a new word.
              word += c;
              inWord = true;
          } 
          else if (char.IsUpper(c))
          {
              // Return the last word.
              yield return word;

              // Start a new string.
              word = string.Empty + c;
              inWord = true;
          }
          else
          {
              // Append to the current string.
              word += c;
          }
      } 
      else
      {
          if (c == '\'' && inWord)
          {
              // If we are at an apostrophe, set and then skip
              last = c;
              continue;
          }

          if (word.Length > 0)
          {
              // Otherwise, if we have a previous word, return.
              yield return word;

              // Clear ready for the next word.
              word = string.Empty;
              inWord = false;
          }
      }

      last = c;
  }

  // If there is one more remaining word, return it.
  if (word.Length > 0)
      yield return word;
}
```

Which you can join/concatentate using

```
string result = string.Join(", ", SplitString(sentence));
```

This method makes use of the compiler's ability to create a state machine when we are using `yield`. This is good, because we can enumerate through the character stream, and return results when we actually obtain them.

Now, this won't directly work in a Razor template, as you'd need to declare a template method. The dirty way of doing it, would be to declare a function using a `Func<string, IEnumerable<string>>` instance:

```
@{
    Func<string, IEnumerable<string>> splitter = s =>
    {
      char last = char.MinValue;
      bool inWord = false;
      string word = string.Empty;

      IList<string> words = new List<string>();

      foreach (char c in s)
      {
          if (char.IsLetter(c))
          {
              if (last == '\'' && char.IsLetter(c) && inWord)
              {
                  word += last;
                  word += c;
                  words.Add(word);

                  word = string.Empty;
                  inWord = false;
              }
              else if (char.IsUpper(c) && !inWord)
              {
                  word += c;
                  inWord = true;
              } 
              else if (char.IsUpper(c))
              {
                  words.Add(word);

                  word = string.Empty + c;
                  inWord = true;
              }
              else
              {
                  word += c;
              }
          } 
          else
          {
              if (c == '\'' && inWord)
              {
                  last = c;
                  continue;
              }

              if (word.Length > 0)
              {
                  words.Add(word);

                  word = string.Empty;
                  inWord = false;
              }
          }

          last = c;
      }

      if (word.Length > 0)
        words.Add(word);

      return words;
    };
  }
```

But even that is not pretty. It's not a bullet proof way of splitting the string correctly either.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer, Matthew! Just looking at the code tells me I'm definitely way out of my depth!